# How to get index of selected Ext.form.field.PickerView item?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How I can to get index of selected Ext.form.field.PickerView item?
I am trying to use it:

```
Ext.define('Bind.CL.FormD.view.MyCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',
alias: 'widget.mycombo',

...something code...

this.on('expand', function () {
            var combo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mycombo')[0];
            var value = combo.getValue(); //or getRawValue();
        }, this);
```

But it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use indexOf() function:
Please Check Fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1i0o

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function() {
    simpsonsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId : 'simpsonsStore',
    fields : ['id','name', 'email'],
    data : [
        {name : 'Lisa',email : 'lisa@simpsons.com',id:1}, 
        {name : 'Bart', email : 'bart@simpsons.com',id:2}, 
        {name : 'Homer', email : 'homer@simpsons.com',id:3},
        {name : 'Marge',email : 'marge@simpsons.com',id:4}
    ]
});

     Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        emptyText: "Hello",
        growMax: 10,
        valueField: 'id',
        store:simpsonsStore,
        displayField: 'name',
        editable: false,
        queryMode: 'local',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners:{
             change:function(combo){
                 console.log(combo.store.indexOf((combo.store.getById(combo.value))));
             }
         }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Please check fiddle

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
this.on('expand', function () {
        var combo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mycombo')[0],
            value = combo.getValue(),
            root = value.store.tree.getRootNode(),
            record = root.childNodes,
            currentValue = combo.getValue().data.Code,
            index = 0;

    Ext.each(record, function(element) {
        var data = element.getData();

        if (data.Code === currentValue) {
            return false;
        }

        index++;     
    });
```